# Azure Function Error: Exception type: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am running into an issue where I can not run any of my Azure Functions locally on my PC. Some of the errors I am seeing are:

> Exception type: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException

as well as

> Exception Azure.RequestFailedException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (169.254.169.254:80) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (169.254.169.254:80)

and the final error is:

> Could not load type Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData

All theses errors are appearing in the function console.

I have tried other's solutions like logging out of Visual Studio and running as admin as well as azurite. Restarted the machine. Updated VS. We have double checked all permissions on Azure portal and have the same permissions as my teammates who are not having this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those urls are usually 127.0.0.1:xxxxx when you're running locally. That IP address is generally for running in a VM. Are you sure your local config is correct?

Answer (score 0):

- Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution before running the function.
- Uninstall Azure function core tools completely and install again.

```
npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
```

- Make sure the `Azure credentials` you have entered are correct. verify the same by running `az login` command in `command line`(check if you are able to login successfully).
- Make sure you have added Azure account in the `Visual Studio=>Tools=>Options=>Accounts`:

[image]

- If you have signed into your account in visual studio, Sign out.
- Go to `Visual Studio=>Tools=>Options=>Azure Service Authentication`, *sign in to your account*:

[image]

- Remove `launchsettings.json` file in your function project and run the function.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue as OP, your answer didnt help. Do you have any idea what cause that issue?